# Issues with Samtools in OSX Catalina, command line cannot find image of Samtools

Tags: python-3.x, macos, command-line, samtools

I spend a good half a day trying various things to solve the following problem when running samtools running on OSX Catalina:
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/brownbear/opt/anaconda3/bin/samtools
      Reason: image not found
    Abort trap: 6

I couldn't even ask command line to tell me which version it was (although I believe it was 1.9), it seems that something in the pair of updated conda and OSX something broke it. I tried everything out there and nothing worked. My last attempt was this and it worked...

was a combination of the following:
https://www.biostars.org/p/173414/

https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/13488

in summary I first did

```
which samtools
```

found the directory, and did

```
rm samtools
```

then ran

```
conda install -c bioconda samtools=1.9=h8ee4bcc_1
```

After this samtools worked, when checking version this is the result:

```
#samtools 1.10
#Using htslib 1.10.2
```

Happy coding all!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, but "conda install -c bioconda samtools=1.9=h8ee4bcc_1" installs the older build which is not compatible with new packages,

Package libcxx conflicts for:
python==3.6.12=h6c3b2c9_0_cpython -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0|>=4.0.1|>=9.0.1']
python==3.6.12=h6c3b2c9_0_cpython -> libcxx[version='>=11.0.0']
samtools==1.9=h8ee4bcc_1 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<6.2.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1']

Although, if you install it in a virtual environment is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, error dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib raise again.